# Adding items to a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'd like to add an element to a list of element. My list is a struct containing a double, an integer and a pointer to the next element. Could someone tell me how to do the Add function please

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Liste Liste;
struct Liste{
    double c;
    int n;
    Liste* next; // pointe sur l'élément suivant
};

void Add(Liste array, Liste item) {
    Liste* last = array.next;
    while (last != NULL) {
        last = last->next;
    }
    array.next = &item;
    printf("%p\n", array.next);
}

int main(){
    Liste array = {12.4, 4, NULL};
    printf("%f\n", array.c);
    Liste item = {15.4, 7, NULL};
    Add(array, item);
    printf("%p\n", array.next);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pass-by-value

In `Add`, C makes a copy of all the function parameters; their scope is the function itself. When one returns, the function parameters are popped from the stack and there is no way to get them back, as you have seen. The way to mutate structures is to pass a pointer to the structure, then modify that pointer using the structure pointer dereference operator, (arrow `->`.)

### Design

The reason one would use a linked-list is it is very cheap to reorder it, but the head of your linked-list is fixed, so you can't change it. You might change this by delineating the container, the list itself, from the contents. This is similar to using a double-pointer, but I think less confusing.

```
struct Noeud {
    double c;
    int n;
    struct Noeud* next; // pointe sur l'élément suivant
};

struct Liste {
    struct Noeud *tete; // singly-linked-list est defini par un pointer seul
};
```

Then you can add, (I've included `assert.h`.)

```
/* `O(n)` */
static void AddQueue(struct Liste *liste, struct Noeud *item) {
    assert(liste && item && item->next == NULL);
    struct Noeud* last = liste->tete;
    if(last == NULL) { // case spécieux
        liste->tete = item;
    } else {
        while (last->next != NULL) {
            last = last->next;
        }
        last->next = item;
    }
}
```

However, it's much simpler and asymptotically faster to add at the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Pointerstructures like a linked list are powerful tools with a wide rage of application.
But first you have to understand pointers.

A pointer is a datastructure which contains the address of a datastructure.

Whenever you call a function the arguments of it are copied (pushed) to the stack.

If the arguments  require a lot of storage space you use a pointer instead.

the code below uses pointers to create a linked list

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdbool.h"


typedef struct List List;

struct List{
  double c;
  int n;
  List *next; 
};


void AddItemEnd( List *RootItem, List *Item )
{
  List *Last = RootItem;
  while( Last->next != NULL )
  {
    Last = Last->next;
  }
  Last->next = Item;
}

void AddItemAtPos( List *RootItem, List *Item, unsigned int Pos )
{
  if( Pos == 0 )
  {
    Item->next = RootItem;
  }
  else
  {
    List *TempItem = RootItem;
    for( unsigned int i = 1; i < Pos && TempItem->next != NULL; ++i  )
    {
      TempItem = TempItem->next;
    }

    Item->next = TempItem->next;
    TempItem->next = Item;
  }
}


void RemoveItemAtPos( List *RootItem, unsigned int Pos )
{
  if( Pos == 0 )
  {
    free( (void*) RootItem );
  }
  else
  {
    List *TempItem = RootItem;

    for( unsigned int i = 1; i < Pos && TempItem->next != NULL; ++i  )
    {
      TempItem = TempItem->next;
    }

    if( TempItem->next == NULL )
    {
      return;

    }else if( TempItem->next->next != NULL )
    {
      List *ItemToDelete = TempItem->next;
      TempItem->next = TempItem->next->next;
      free( (void*) ItemToDelete );
    
    }else
    {
      free( (void*) TempItem->next );
      TempItem->next =NULL;
    }
  }
}



int main(void) {
  List *RootItem = malloc( sizeof( List )); 
  RootItem->c = 12.4;
  RootItem->n =  4;
  RootItem->next = NULL;

  List *Item1 = malloc( sizeof(List ));
  Item1->c = 15.4; 
  Item1->n = 7;
  Item1->next = NULL ;

  AddItemEnd( RootItem, Item1 );

  List *IterationItem;

  printf( "List created with AddItemEnd()\n\n" );
  for( IterationItem = RootItem; IterationItem != NULL; IterationItem = IterationItem->next )
  {
    printf( "c: %lf\nn: %d\n\n", IterationItem->c, IterationItem->n );
  }



  List *item2 = malloc( sizeof( List ));
  item2->c = 23.4;
  item2->n = 1846;
  item2->next = NULL ;

  AddItemAtPos( RootItem, item2, 1 );

  printf( "\n\nList extended with AddItemAtPos()\n\n");
  for( IterationItem = RootItem; IterationItem != NULL; IterationItem = IterationItem->next )
  {
    printf( "c: %lf\nn: %d\n\n", IterationItem->c, IterationItem->n );
  }
  
  RemoveItemAtPos(RootItem, 1 );

  printf( "\n\nList after RemoveItemAtPos()\n\n");
  for( IterationItem = RootItem; IterationItem != NULL; IterationItem = IterationItem->next )
  {
    printf( "c: %lf\nn: %d\n\n", IterationItem->c, IterationItem->n );
  }
  free( (void*) RootItem );
  free( (void*) item2 );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key elements when dealing with lists is pointers
and using memory allocation.

If we disregard your add function and just do a simple
example you will probably get the geist of it.

First allocate you starting list like this

```
Liste* array = malloc(sizeof(Liste));
```

Now you have one uninitialized block of memory
that `array` points to. You then need to initialize
it.

```
array->c = 12.4;
array->n = 4;
array->next = NULL;
```

in order to add a new entry to your list you
need to again allocate memory for the next node and
initialize it plus set the previous node next pointer
to point to it i.e. `array->next`.

```
Liste* item = malloc(sizeof(Liste));
item->c = 15.4;
item->n = 7;
item->next = NULL;
array->next = item;
```

now you have a list of two elements where array points
to the first

printing your short list

```
Liste* p = array;
while (p != NULL)
{
  printf("%lf %d %p\n", p->c, p->n, p->next);
  p = p->next;
}
```

So your Add functions does not allocate memory and copies
the parameters so that is not going to work.

Your Add function should have a pointer either to either the first or last item in your list e.g.

```
void Add(Liste* start, double c, int n)
```

Then you do as I showed you above and create a new node and assign the values

If you want to be able to pass an empty list to Add then you need to do differently, since `start` is copied it cannot be changed, you need to pass the address of the pointer

```
void Add(List** start, double c, int n)
{
  Liste* node = malloc(sizeof(Liste));
  ...
  (* put node in the list *)
  if (*start == NULL)
  {
    *start = node; // first
  }
  else
  {
    (* find last node, see print loop *)
    (* once you have last item, set it to point to node)
  }
  ...
}

int main()
{
  Liste* start = NULL;
  Add(&start, 12.4, 4);
  Add(&start, 15.4, 7);
  ...
```